# E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, sudo, repository

I have had this error since last month and I haven't found a way to solve it until now. Whenever I run the `sudo apt update` command it shows `E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.` error message and I don't find any solution for it, for the moment my computer works perfectly. Still, I think it is way better to solve the error right now.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249177/e-the-repository-http-ppa-launchpad-net-certbot-certbot-ubuntu-focal-release), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file), and [this](https://www.linuxtechi.com/fix-repository-release-file-error-ubuntu/) posts but but none works for me.

Thank you if you can help

Comment: Remove this ppa it does not support newer ubuntu releases.

Comment: PPAs are *Personal Package Archives* or 3rd party sources, so all security & *fitness for purpose* checks are your responsibility; it appears you didn't perform sufficient checks prior to adding that 3rd party *personal package archive*.

Comment: Hello everyone, I just found a way to solve it that was in Software and updates > Other software and unchecking the `xorg-drivers` links and that was it.